# removing time overlap from single table group by catagory1 catagory2

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date, datetime, hive

hive preferred 
or 
sql 
remove time overlap

```
catagory1 catagory2 timestart time_end  
1         A        4:00     5:00
1         A        2:30     4:30
1         A        3:30     5:00
1         A        5:00     7:00
1         A        8:00     9:00
2         A        4:00     5:00
1         B        4:00     5:00
```

removing time overlap from single table group by catagory1 catagory2

result looks like

```
catagory1 catagory2 timestart time_end  
1         A        4:00        5:00
1         A        5:00        7:00
1         A        8:00        9:00
2         A        4:00        5:00
1         B        4:00        5:00
```

Comment: MySql, Sql Server and Hive are 3 very different products. Which one of them do you really work with?

Comment: I'm working in hive